# Flow Slow Performance

Tags: visual-studio-code, flowtype

I've tried using flow with VS Code and it always takes approximately 7 - 8 seconds to save any single file even after multiple saves. This makes it very hard to use flow as I have to wait so long just to see results. I think it might be a problem with my configuration, but even on new fresh codebases I have this issue. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling flow and even node a few times to no avail.

VSCode version information:

- Flow 0.46.0
- VS Code 1.12.2
- flowtype.flow-for-vscode 0.6.0 (no other plugins or themes installed)
- Node v.7.10.0

Comment: Approximately how large is your project? This isn't unusual if you are editing a file that has on the order of hundreds of downstream dependencies, which all get rechecked when you save your file. If you are editing a file that has no, or few, downstream dependencies it should be much faster.

Comment: The code base is fairly large at 3k JS files. Even if I add a new function thats not used elsewhere the save operation is still that slow. Is my codebase in general just too large for flow?

Comment: Flow doesn't track dependencies at the function level currently, only the module level. If you add a new file that is not used elsewhere, is it still slow?

Comment: It is faster if I create a new file with just a simple function to add two numbers, in this case it takes about 1 second if that. My test case for the slowdown is I go to an existing file, of which I've tried a few, and once in that file I look for a function only used in that specific file and change a parameter type to be incorrect. The subsequent save in which I run flow will take the 7 - 8 seconds to complete. Typical file size in which I run the test is around 100 lines.

Comment: Yep, this is basically expected at this point. It's a big gripe inside Facebook as well. I'm actually doing some work right now to send errors down to the IDE as they are computed (so you will get errors for the current file quickly, and downstream errors later). This will initially be integrated with Nuclide. There has been some perf work lately on Flow which has been improving things and I think a lot of people want that to continue. There are certainly a number of potential optimizations that remain, it's just a matter of getting to them.

Comment: Thanks Nat! It really helps to have some clarity and I appreciate the hard work you and the team put into flow. I look forward to the performance increases over time.